# How to take a the top ranked value from the rightmost column in a join

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to perform a query where I sort by a users roles. 
Users have companies. Users have roles at that company.

Tables:

```
USER
id

USER_HAS_COMPANY_ROLES
user_id
company_role_id

COMPANY_ROLES
id
name
```

The company roles that exist are either 'admin' or 'member'. Users can have either 'member' role or both 'member' and 'admin' roles.

I want to get all users of a company, but sort the users by the most important roles. In this case the most important role is 'admin'. But since a user can be both 'member' and 'admin' I need to first sort the roles in the order of importance and then take the most important so I can properly execute my ORDER BY clause.

I cannot use the company_role_id for ordering because more roles will be added in the future and we can't rely on the id's being in order of the most important role.

I have tried several ways of filtering the results but none seem to work

I want to essentially JOIN on USER_HAS_COMPANY_ROLES and sort those roles by the COMPANY_ROLES name and then take the top role and return that top role as the record for the JOIN statement

```sql
SELECT users.email, company_roles.name FROM `users`
JOIN `user_has_company_roles`
ON `user_has_company_roles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN`company_roles`
ON `company_roles`.`id` = `user_has_company_roles`.`company_role_id`
WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` is null 
ORDER BY CASE
              WHEN company_roles.name = 'member' THEN 1
              WHEN company_roles.name = 'admin' THEN 0
         END
```

This statement works but I have 1 admin user in my test data. This admin user has both the 'member' and the 'admin' role and so that user will be listed twice in the results

The results I'm getting from the above query are:

```
EMAIL            NAME
admin@aol.com    admin
user@aol.com     member
admin@aol.com    member
```

The results I'm looking for are

```
EMAIL            NAME
admin@aol.com    admin
user@aol.com     member
```

Comment: Can you add an `importance` column to the `company_roles` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` seems like a simple approach

```
SELECT u.email,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(cr.name = 'admin') > 0 THEN 'admin'
             WHEN SUM(cr.name = 'user') > 0 THEN 'user'
        END) as best_role
FROM users u JOIN
     user_has_company_roles ucr
     ON ucr.user_id = u.id JOIN
     company_roles cr
     ON ucr.company_role_id = cr.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.email;
```